# unique rows in data frame based on if's

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

I have a large data table (millions of rows), where I need to trim the rows down to one per ID. The rule is that if another art than "X" is in the unique ID, 
the X'es should be deleted. But if no other art is in the Unique ID, the X should stay.

Test dataset:

```
dt <- data.table(
  ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4),
  art=c("X", "Y", "X", "X", "X", "X", "Z", "X"),
  redskb=c("a", "Y", "a", "b", "b", "c", "k", "n")
)

   ID art redskb
1:  1   X      a
2:  1   Y      Y
3:  1   X      a
4:  2   X      b
5:  2   X      b
6:  3   X      c
7:  4   X      k
8:  4   Z      n
```

Required output:

```
    ID art redskb
1:  1   Y      Y   
2:  2   X      b
3:  3   X      c
4:  4   Z      n
```

I tried with

```
unique(dt, by = c("ID"))
```

but could not get it to work efficiently with if's.

Comment: Maybe something like `unique(dt)[, flag := if (.N == 1) TRUE else art != "X", ID][(flag)]`?

Comment: there's an issue in your example, what you printed is not what you defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**data.table:**

```
dt[order(ID,art=="X"),.SD[1],ID]
```

or @Frank's version:

```
unique(dt[order(ID,art == "X")], by="ID")

#    ID art redskb
# 1:  1   Y      Y
# 2:  2   X      b
# 3:  3   X      c
# 4:  4   Z      k
```

**dplyr:**

```
dt %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(which.max(art != "X"))
#   # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   # Groups:   ID [4]
#        ID    art redskb
#     <dbl> <fctr>  <chr>
#   1     1      Y      Y
#   2     2      X      b
#   3     3      X      c
#   4     4      Z      k
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd try something like this:

```
unique(dt)[, `:=`(flag, if (.N == 1) TRUE else art != "X"), ID][(flag)]
##    ID art redskb flag
## 1:  1   Y      Y TRUE
## 2:  2   X      b TRUE
## 3:  3   X      c TRUE
## 4:  4   Z      k TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do

```
dt[dt[, .I[if(uniqueN(art) >1 & any(art == "X")) art!="X" else  seq_len(.N)==1], ID]$V1]
#   ID art redskb
#1:  1   Y      Y
#2:  2   X      b
#3:  3   X      c
#4:  4   Z      k
```